# C++ Random errors in a copied library

Tags: c++

I copied a Big Int Library into my code and I'm having random errors in one of the classes. (The code is older)

One of my errors is in a define statement, not really sure how these work.
Everything under "tmpthis;" is giving an error.

```
#define DTRT_ALIASED(cond, op) \
if (cond) {\

    BigUnsigned tmpThis; 
    tmpThis.op; //Error: no storage class or type specifier
    *this = tmpThis; //Error: *this expected an identifier Error: No suitable conversion from "BigUnsigned" to "int" exists.
    return; // Error: expected a declaration
} \
```

On top of that there are a few random if and for statements with the error "expected a declaration" and some variables with the error " no storage class or type specifier"

NOTE: these random errors also had instances where they were not errors also, it was inconsistent.

Comment: That MACRO should only be used in a class method. it seems you have prior errors which may compiler think your are not in class method.

Comment: You might have include problem.

Comment: Nothing is random.

Comment: There should be a backslash at the end of every line of the macro, and no backslash on the last line.

Comment: @Jarod42 This is in a class if that is what you mean, no include problem either I've tried

Comment: @Barmar Doing this did fix 3 of the errors but return still has an error and the closing bracket does as well. The "DTRT_ALIASED" has an error when it is declared later on.

Comment: You're probably not using it correctly. As @Jarod said, you can only use this macro inside a member function, because it needs to use `this`.

Comment: @JeffLoughlin Particle physicists will not agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

A bare-bones fix to the macro is:

```
#define DTRT_ALIASED(cond, op) \
    if (cond) { \
        BigUnsigned tmpThis; \
        tmpThis.op; \
        *this = tmpThis; \
        return; \
    }
```

This stands a chance of compiling when used in a function that doesn't return a value, if the reference to `op` in `tmpThis.op` makes sense to the compiler.  It is somewhat peculiar (and limited) code, but there might be a use for it.